# React routing issue on server at local environment everything working fine

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am facing a routing issue in react. Everything is working fine on the local environment but when I am creating a build and moving my code onto the production server I am getting a routing issue after refreshing the page. If I am refreshing the page getting error page not found but if I am not refreshing the page everything working fine.

Comment: Please include relevant codes ([Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and error messages. Otherwise it would be very difficult to know what's wrong just from your description

Comment: Do you have a backend environment for your services using same URL?

Comment: You need to configure your server to rewrite all requests, to non-existing resources, to your index page, and then your app will pick up the routing from there.